# MS Exchange - Public Reservations For Calendar (similar to www.youcanbook.me)

Tags: exchange, guest, calendar

Does Exchange (or Office 365 Exchange hosting) offer any functionality similar to www.youcanbook.me, where people who are not members of an organization (and do not have login credentials) can make appointments/reservations on a shared calendar? Or would the only way to accomplish this would be to publish credentials on a website to a "guest" Exchange/OWA account, and give the "guest" account Non-editing Author permissions to the shared calendar?

Comment: Is this a Public Folder calendar?

Comment: I haven't ever been confronted with this one, but a quick Google found this: http://blog.orbitone.com/post/Online-Meeting-Room-Reservation-for-Exchange if you are interested.  I'm not aware of such a feature in O365 though.

Comment: @joequery, it could be

Comment: @TheCleaner thanks. It is less than ideal since it requires a Live account.